# Как скрыть statusBar в ios?

Tags: unity3d, xcode

Запуская на ios unity у меня не исчезает statusBar, он становится прозрачным, но остается. Как его убрать?

Comment: поясните, пожалуйста, что вы понимаете под toolbar? потому что в терминах ios подобной вещи нет

Comment: Я понимаю верхнюю панельку со времен состоянием оператора и состоянием заряда(Я перепутал. Я имел ввиду status bar). Я их в юнити пытаюсь спрятать через player setting. но все равно она появляется. Как сделать, чтобы ее небыло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать следующие варианты:

1. [Плагин](https://github.com/HuaYe1975/UnityStatusBarForiOS) на Github, простой и легкий, который с помощью нативного кода убирает StatusBar.
2. StatusBar можно скрыть, если добавить соответствующий ключ в Info.plist файл вашего Xcode проекта Вам нужно добавить ключ `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` и значение `UIStatusBarHidden`, а также ключ `UIStatusBarHidden` и значение `YES`. Это можно сделать руками (в качестве инструкции используя [ответ из этой ссылки](https://www.quora.com/Why-must-the-status-bar-always-be-visible-in-iOS)), либо с помощью пост-процесса (за основу можно взять пост-процесс из [этого ответа с официального форума](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-can-you-add-items-to-the-xcode-project-targets-info-plist-using-the-xcodeapi.330574/#post-2143867))
3. Посмотреть еще один [плагин](https://github.com/FooStudio/flutter_statusbar_manager) с Github.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте что-то вроде `PlayerSettings.statusBarHidden = true` при старте сцены

Comment: а вы документацию по PlayerSettings посмотрите внимательно. Этот класс доступен только в редакторе, и при старте сцены использовать его не получится
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.html

Comment: @vmchar, ну так эти настройки ставятся в редакторе, а билд уже с ними зашимается, все так и должно работать, разве нет?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker в редакторе ставятся. Например в пост-процессе можно включить или выключить. Но в рантайме с помощью этого метода не получится значение поменять. Хотя в нативе на Obj-c можно и в рантайме с помощью одного метода менять видимость

Comment: @vmchar, Могут тогда будут какие-нибудь преложения как убрать statusBar?